# How to access Android Phone Hardware /Events?

Tags: android

How to access Android Phone Hardware /Events?
i know (as a new developer) it is 'long way to go' to access android phone built-in hard ware & Call events & use it my app.
Still any tips that may be effective for me to obtain these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to learn every hardware event for now as you are new to android. But you can ask(or search) questions about whatever hardware events you want to handle in your app.

For an example,
If you want a hardware back button event, you can simply override it from Activity like this :

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    // do your call here

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: If this helped you, you can upvote and accept the ans. Thanks.